# How to configure -fno-strict-aliasing?

Tags: c

I am trying to use autogen and configure to generate a Makefile in a third-party code.   I want to add `–fno-strict-aliasing` to the gcc to get around a compiling problem in the code.

I guess this can done in the ./configure stage but not totally sure.  I have tried the following, but none worked:

```
./configure –fno-strict-aliasing
./configure –with-no-strict-aliasing
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `configure` with `CFLAGS` set to what you want.

```
./configure "CFLAGS=-O3 -fno-strict-aliasing"
```

Alternatively call `make` with the desired options (IMO this is better).

Comment: If you pass the options to `make`, (1) it will sabotage the configuration tests, which should be run with the same `CFLAGS` as your project, and (2) you will have to remember to supply `CFLAGS` to many calls to `make` instead of just one call to `configure`, increasing the risk of an inconsistent build.